# Loading two-way recursive relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In a project I'm currently working on, I have to link two entities of the same model together, creating a recursive relation. This will create an entry in the database in which one of the entities is marked as the 'parent_entity' and the other as the 'child_entity'. Therefore, I am able to load the parents of an entity and the children of an entity separately. However, I would like to be able to load both the relations simultaneously and return them together. Would this be in any way possible?

Here is what I came up with up until now, although now I'm not yet able to call `entity->load('linkedDatasets')`

```
class Dataset extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use Encryptable;
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    public function parentDatasets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dataset::class, 'linked_datasets', 'dataset_id', 
            'linked_dataset_id');
    }

    public function childDatasets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Dataset::class, 'linked_datasets', 'linked_dataset_id', 
            'dataset_id');
    }

    public function linkedDatasets() {
        $children = $this->childDatasets;
        $parents = $this->parentDatasets;
        return $parents->merge($children);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why are you not able to call that specific method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method works fine, but instead of loading the new method, which you can't due to it being a method not a relation, just include them with the `with()` method.

```
Dataset::with('parentDatasets', 'childDatasets')->get($id);
```

If you are using standard transformation, you can convert the method to an [getter](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to make it act like an database column. Now you can fetch it as `$dataset->linked_datasets`. Bonus points, concat is more effective than merge.

```
public function getLinkedDatasetsAttrbiute() {
    $children = $this->childDatasets;
    $parents = $this->parentDatasets;
    return $parents->concat($children);
}
```

Now you just append it to the `Dataset.php` model., for it to be automatically serialized.

```
protected $appends = ['linked_datasets'];
```

Comment: appends calls `linked_datasets()` method every time you fetch the Model. I don't think this will be a good way to go

Comment: @AnujShrestha no appends are only added when serializing the model

Comment: @lagbox bad wording from my side. But whenever eloquent fetch records from Database appends will be included in the eloquent result set right? If yes this will be just extra unnecessary query.

Comment: @AnujShrestha no it is only when the model is **serialized**

Comment: @lagbox oh did not know about that. Thanks for correcting me. Looks like I will have to look into Eloquent serialization again.

Comment: @mrhn This did indeed solve my problem. Thank you for the quick response!